# Run a groovy class file without main method using gradle task

Tags: gradle

I have a class file which does not have a main method. I need to run the class file only when needed with the help of a gradle task. Can someone help me with writing a gradle task for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess it'd be something like

```
buildscript {
    // add your library to the buildscript classpath
    classpath 'foo.bar:mygroovylib:1.0'
}

task runMyGroovy {
    // let's assume your service accepts an input file and writes to an output directory
    File inFile = file('path/to/some/file.xml')
    File outDir = file("$buildDir/myGroovy")

    // set task inputs/outputs to benefit from gradle's up-to-date checks
    inputs.file inFile
    outputs.dir outDir

    doLast {
       // actually do stuff in gradle's execution phase
       def myObject = new MyGroovyObject();
       myObject.doSomethingFantastic(inFile, outDir)
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to just run a .groovy file and everything else is taken care in it. so can you edit ur code according to it. I am not taking any input files.